# Wrong divergence message for the continued fraction

Tags: bugs, number-theory

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and fixed in 11.2**

---

Why there is an error message for `ContinuedFractionK[k, 1, {k, Infinity}]`?

[image]

It is well known that, this continued fraction converges to

$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{e \pi
   }}}{\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-1.$$

Comment: In 11.2, `ContinuedFractionK[k, 1, {k, Infinity}]` is now left unevaluated, without an error message showing up.

Comment: In MMA 11.3 BUG occurs again!!!